# Python pandas: can we avoid apply in this case of groupby/apply?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-apply

I have been hearing a lot about pandas apply is slow and should be used as least as possible.

In the following situation, I need to compute the column `Pct_Change_Adjusted` without using apply:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04'],
          'Fund_ID': [9072, 9072, 9072],
          'Fund_Series': ['A', 'A', 'A'],
          'Value': [1020.0, 1040.4, 1009.188],
          'Dividend': [0.0, 0.0, 52.02]})
```

I would like to do some adjusted weighting operation as given below after the grouping:

```
df['Pct_Change_Adjusted'] = df.groupby(['Fund_ID', 'Fund_Series'], as_index=False) \
                              .apply(lambda x: (x.Value + x.Dividend)/(x.Value.shift()+x.Dividend.shift())  ) \
                              .reset_index(drop=True).values[0]

print(df)

         Date  Dividend  Fund_ID Fund_Series     Value  Pct_Change_Adjusted
0  2019-01-02      0.00     9072           A  1020.000                  NaN
1  2019-01-03      0.00     9072           A  1040.400                 0.02
2  2019-01-04     52.02     9072           A  1009.188                 0.02
```

Are there any alternatives to `apply()` here that will increase the efficiency or at least a second way of doing this?

Note: I am not talking about dask and other parallization, only pure pandas.

Comment: FYI: [using `.values` accessor is deprecated, use `.to_numpy()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is 100% vectorizable using `groupby.pct_change`:

```
(df.Value + df.Dividend).groupby([df.Fund_ID, df.Fund_Series]).pct_change()

0     NaN
1    0.02
2    0.02
dtype: float64
```

---

```
df['Pct_Change_Adjusted'] = (df.assign(Foo=df['Value'] + df['Dividend'])
                               .groupby(['Fund_ID', 'Fund_Series'])
                               .Foo
                               .pct_change())

df

         Date  Fund_ID Fund_Series     Value  Dividend  Pct_Change_Adjusted
0  2019-01-02     9072           A  1020.000      0.00                  NaN
1  2019-01-03     9072           A  1040.400      0.00                 0.02
2  2019-01-04     9072           A  1009.188     52.02                 0.02
```

Comment: Is there a reason you did `.groupby([df['Fund_ID'], df['Fund_Series']])` instead of `.groupby(['Fund_ID', 'Fund_Series'])` ?

Comment: @Erfan Yes. `(df.Value + df.Dividend)` returns a series. Unless I assign the series back to `df`, I cannot pass strings to groupby, I have to pass the columns/series directly.  Edited for clarity.

Comment: In the former case, I called Series.GroupBy. Now, after editing, I call DataFrame.GroupBy.